# WiFi module in an android application

Tags: android, webserver, wifi, remote-control

My project is to develop a remote home control using an android application and web server integrated in a  Raspberry pi and communicate with an Arduino cart so to do this thing I have to use a WiFi module in my android application.

How to develop this module in my application?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you gona do?
http://blog.arduino.cc/2014/10/13/wood-lizzie-is-a-diy-soap-box-cart/

If you are looking for a wifi module for rasperi-pi

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Raspberry-Pi-WIFI-Dongle-Wireless/dp/B00GRYQAXE/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1426870448&sr=8-6&keywords=wifi+dongle+raspberry+pi